# How can I take more specific errors on angularjs es6 webpack application

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am using webpack for es6 compilation, 
when my code has errors like the following

```
export default angular.module('my module')
  .controller('MyController',MyController)***;***
  .controller('MyController2',MyController2)
```

I am getting very general error message, is there any configuration or tool that I can use to get more specific error messages ?

Comment: Is this a webpack error or angular, also whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, if it is a webpack error try the following:

```
webpack --display-error-details
```